# Making task manager icon match desktop icon?

Tags: kubuntu, kde, icons

Ubuntu 21.04, KDE Plasma 5.21.4

I have two xfreerdp shortcuts on the desktop (pointed to different servers, of course) and each shortcut has a different icon assigned so that I can tell them apart at a glance (the text caption is a little hard to read.) On the taskbar, however, the icons for the application are used, so they're both the same.

Is it possible to have the taskbar use the same icons as the desktop shortcuts? If so, how?

Thanks!